# Why the changes in list1 doesnt gets reflected in list2?

Tags: python, list

The id of `li[3]` and `li1[0]` is same, but even then the changes at `0`, the index in `li1` doesn't gets reflected in `li`. Why?

```
list1=[1,2,3,4,5]
list2=list1[3:]
print(id(list1[3])==id(list2[0]))
list2[0]=7
print(list1,list2)
```

Comment: `print(id(list1)==id(list2))` is `False`

Comment: Why do you think it should?

Comment: You're just printing the ID of the number `4`, that has nothing to do with the list elements.

Comment: Because `list1 is not list2`. `id` is giving you the `id` of *the object tat those indices*, which happens to be the same integer object. That has nothing to do with the list objects. You cannot get the `id` of  the index, that doesn't mean anything. `id` belongs to *objects*

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Id of integer objects are different and has nothing to do with the list. If you print list ids, they will be different. You are printing id of the integer and will be the same as long as python reuse that integer object in a single run. (I am not sure about the details of the implementations but seems that python reuses the same integer object for ranges of -5 to 255 as long as large numbers (of order of 2^30) are not calculated in the process of creating the integer object).

To better understand that, here is an example that creates two independent lists and prints id of same integer and lists:

```
list1=[1,2,3,4,5]
list2=[4,5]
print(list1[3], id(list1[3]))
print(list2[0], id(list2[0]))
print(list1, id(list1))
print(list2, id(list2))
```

output:

```
4 4402473872
4 4402473872
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 4404019680
[4, 5] 4404022240
```

Comment: For whoever that down voted, could you please explain (/help edit) why this is not the correct answer?

Comment: This is either wrong or misleadingly phrased. Multiple `int` objects may represent the same integer, so taking the ID of "the same integer" in different lists (or not in lists - the lists don't matter) may yield different results. For example, [this demo shows 2 IDs for `1000`](https://ideone.com/MF3E7H).

Comment: brother thanks for your answer i was just  mixed two concepts here, i just thought that here both list are referring to same object but actually they are not.

Comment: You are welcome. If that answers your question, please go ahead and accept it so others can find it useful too.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Thank you for the note. I just edited to include the range of numbers with constant ids in python which is -5 to 255. In the example you included, it refers to id(1000) which is out of the range and not unique.

Comment: That's a common misconception. [Even in the -5 to 256 range, you can have multiple `int` objects for the same int.](https://ideone.com/UfepPN)

Comment: Can you please provide an example here to help fix it? Thank you. I checked your example and it returns the same id for the range of -5 to 255. Although different runs will provide different objects of course.

Comment: I just provided an example, in the link. [Here it is again.](https://ideone.com/UfepPN)

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Doesn't the linked example show a different id because you are creating a number larger than 2^31-1 in your calculations and create a different object?

Comment: No. The result of the calculation is `1`. You can see that in the printed output.

Comment: [Here's a simpler example, without modular exponentiation.](https://ideone.com/ezHyDo) (I actually thought modular exponentiation was the only example before I took a closer look, but either the implementation changed since the last time I looked, or I read it wrong before.)

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica The final result is 1, however, you create 5**25-1 in the process of calculation which is essentially a large number. If you try the same example with smaller numbers , the ids will become the same. Similar case applies to your last example. All of them create large numbers and hence create a different object (Not sure how python internally deals with it or what number is exactly the cutoff for changes of object)

Comment: It's still a counterexample to the claim in your answer. Your answer shouldn't even focus on the implementation details of when int objects get reused, anyway; the relevant part is that they happened to be reused. Going into the implementation details invites people to rely on them as if they were guarantees.

Comment: Thanks for the note. I will edit the post to include this.